# How to know a particular value is available or not in a complex JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angular, rxjs

I have a json like this

```
 myPermission=[  
   {  
      "root_permission_name":"HR",
      "root_pk":3,
      "child_list":[  
         {  
            "child_pk":8,
            "child_permission_name":"Employee Management",
            "sub_child_list":[  

            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "root_permission_name":"Finance",
      "root_pk":8,
      "child_list":[  
         {  
            "child_pk":20,
            "child_permission_name":"Fees",
            "sub_child_list":[  
               {  
                  "sub_child_permission_name":"Create Fees",
                  "sub_child_pk":5
               },
               {  
                  "sub_child_permission_name":"Schedule Fee Collection Dates ",
                  "sub_child_pk":6
               }                  
            ]
         },
         {  
            "child_pk":21,
            "child_permission_name":"Category",
            "sub_child_list":[  

            ]
         },             
         {  
            "child_pk":26,
            "child_permission_name":"Finance Reports",
            "sub_child_list":[  
               {  
                  "sub_child_permission_name":"Report",
                  "sub_child_pk":17
               },
               {  
                  "sub_child_permission_name":"Compare Transection",
                  "sub_child_pk":18
               },
               {  
                  "sub_child_permission_name":"Fee Receipts",
                  "sub_child_pk":19
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Is there a way that i can know whether the particular value (e.g. "Fees") is available or not in my json without using FOR loop ?

It will be appreciable if anyone solve this through RXJS.

Note : I dont have to use for loop

Comment: Rxjs is for async events. This is a static collection. Even if there is a way to do it using Rxjs this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: how should the result look like?

Comment: How do you get this list? From an HTTP request?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: JSON is a dynamic. it is coming via http request.

Comment: Why can't you / don't you want to use a `for` loop?

Comment: i have to display the content on my template according to permission which i am getting through http request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
var presence = JSON.stringify(yourJSON).indexOf('"Fees"') > -1;
```

or maybe this:

```
var presence = JSON.stringify(yourJSON).indexOf(':"Fees"') > -1;
```

I am just stringifying your `object` and then checking the presence of `"Fees"`. If it is -1 then it is not present otherwise it is.

Comment: thanks void ! Now i got the answer which i am looking for.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I think either the question is misleading. This shows if the JSON contains a key, but doesn't create a list of elements that match a filter. That's what I'd expect from a filter.

Comment: I guess the question is pretty much clear `Is there a way that i can know whether the particular value (e.g. "Fees") is available or not in my json without using FOR loop ?`.

Comment: That's what I upvoted your answer for (reading to the end ;-) ) but the question title is misleading.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer definitely the title is misleading. OP can you please think of something better?

Comment: @void why to use `('"Fees"') ` instead of `('Fees') ` ? asking you because both produces different response ? and does this search `Index` for the deep level of array into array ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that i can know whether the particular value (e.g. "Fees") is available or not in my json without using FOR loop ?

I assume you mean a `for` loop or any other looping construct. If so, the answer is "No, there isn't, not reasonably anyway."

So instead, you use a looping construct. Specifically, *nested* looping constructs, since `Fees` is on a child list:

```
var hasFees = myPermission.some(function(entry) {
    return entry.child_list.some(function(child) {
        return child.child_permission_name == "Fees";
    });
});
```

`Array#some` calls its callback once for each entry in the array, stopping the first time the callback returns a truthy value. Its return value is `true` if the callback ever returned a truthy value, or `false` if not. So it's handy for searches like this.

**Live Example:**

```js
var myPermission = [{
    "root_permission_name": "HR",
    "root_pk": 3,
    "child_list": [{
        "child_pk": 8,
        "child_permission_name": "Employee Management",
        "sub_child_list": [

        ]
    }]
}, {
    "root_permission_name": "Finance",
    "root_pk": 8,
    "child_list": [{
        "child_pk": 20,
        "child_permission_name": "Fees",
        "sub_child_list": [{
            "sub_child_permission_name": "Create Fees",
            "sub_child_pk": 5
        }, {
            "sub_child_permission_name": "Schedule Fee Collection Dates ",
            "sub_child_pk": 6
        }]
    }, {
        "child_pk": 21,
        "child_permission_name": "Category",
        "sub_child_list": [

        ]
    }, {
        "child_pk": 26,
        "child_permission_name": "Finance Reports",
        "sub_child_list": [{
            "sub_child_permission_name": "Report",
            "sub_child_pk": 17
        }, {
            "sub_child_permission_name": "Compare Transection",
            "sub_child_pk": 18
        }, {
            "sub_child_permission_name": "Fee Receipts",
            "sub_child_pk": 19
        }]
    }]
}];
var hasFees = myPermission.some(function(entry) {
    return entry.child_list.some(function(child) {
        return child.child_permission_name == "Fees";
    });
});
document.body.innerHTML = hasFees;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you ask for. Based on the question, my guess is that this is an assignment where the teacher want the students to perform this in a functional approach rather than an imperative one. Hence the "no for loop" criteria.

The following function will iterate through all values, recursively, in the json and look for a specific value. If that value exists (no matter the property name) it'll return true.

It uses [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which will "tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function."

```
var hasPerm = myPermission
   .some(function (arr) {
      return hasPermission(arr, 'Fees') 
   });

console.log(hasPerm); // true/false

function hasPermission(arr, needle) {
   return Object
      .keys(arr)
      .some(function(key) {
         if (typeof arr[key] === 'object') {
            return hasPermission(arr[key], needle);
         } else {
            return arr[key] === needle;
         }
      })
}
```

It can easily be extended to only look for the value at certain properties. As [RxJS also has the `some` method](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/some.md) it shouldn't be any problem to use in that context.